# The method returns true if the integer is divisible by 3 and returns false if the integer is not divisible by 3

Tags: java, boolean

This is what I have so far; I have to use this main method.

```
public class HW4 {

    public static boolean isDivisibleByThree(String n) {
        int sum = 0;
        int value;

        for (int k = 0; k < n.length(); k++) {
            char ch = n.charAt(k);
            value = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            sum = sum*value;
        }
        return sum*3 == 0;
    }
}
```

It always comes out true and I'm really stuck in this part. So if you can, can you help me out?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you are not allowed to use the `%` operator?

Comment: As long as i use this public static boolean isDivisibleByThree(String n)

Comment: it works for divisible by 3; problem now is that if it is a negative integer it should always be false… anyone know?

Comment: oh thanks sorry i'm all new at this.

Answer (score 1):

A *sum* is a cumulative *addition* (not multiplication).

Change this line:

```
sum = sum * value;
```

To

```
sum = sum + value;
```

Or the more brief version:

```
sum += value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `sum = sum * value`? This should probably be `sum = sum + value`, or short `sum += value`
2. `sum * 3 == 0` should probably be `sum % 3 == 0`

If you are required to not use the `%` operator, you could alternatively do:

```
double check = (double)sum / 3.0;
return check == (int)check;
```

---

The problem with negative numbers is that the `-` gets parsed too, you could sove it by dropping it:

```
if (n[0] == '-') {
    n = n.substring(1);
}
```

This drops the sign if it is negative and does nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier solution: use the mod-function:

```
int number = int.Parse(input);
bool result = (number % 3 == 0);
```

Comment: The user is **not** allowed to use the ``%`` operator in his method.

Comment: @ThreeFx : who said this?

Comment: @vsz Bob's comment following your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you would first use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to parse the `int` from the `String`. Then you can divide that value by 3 using integer division. Finally, test if that number multiplied by 3 is the original value.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(n);
int third = value / 3;
return (value == third * 3);
```